# How to right align text relative to the word above?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exsheets

I use `exsheets` to generate some exercise papers. The layout looks like this:

- first comes the word EXERCISE
- under the word EXERCISE are the exercises, which are numbered within the section

I would like the numbers of the exercises right aligned under the word EXERCISE. I figured out how to hardcode the spacing so it looks like right aligned. When you have more than 9 chapters (like I have) this workaround doesn't work anymore.

**This is the alignment I want...**

[image]

**...but if I hardcode the spacing for chapters 10+ it doesn't work for chapters 10-**

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{hugeIndent}{default}{
  runin = true,
  attach = {main[r,vc]number[l,vc](-3.8em,0pt)} % right alignment hardcoded
}

\SetupExSheets{
  headings=hugeIndent,
  question/pre-hook=\begin{addmargin}[4.6em]{0cm},
  question/post-hook=\end{addmargin},
  counter-within={section},
  counter-format=ch.se.qu[1]
}

\begin{document}
  \part{EXCERCISES}
    \chapter{Topic 1}

      \section{Section}

        Exercise
        \begin{question}
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm a solution.
        \end{solution}

      \section{Section}

        Exercise
        \begin{question}
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm a solution.
        \end{solution}

  \setcounter{chapter}{9}     

    \chapter{Topic 2}

      \section{Section}

        Exercise
        \begin{question}
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm a solution.
        \end{solution}

      \section{Section}
       Exercise
       \begin{question}
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm a solution.
        \end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What comes first in my mind, is to make some boxes. One with the width of `Exercise`, and a second one for `I'm a ...`. In the first box, you align the text right, in the second box, you use raggedbottom.

Comment: Another idea would be to make the hardcode condintional. i.e. `ifnum\value{topicnumber}>10 \hardspace=x \else \hardspace=y \fi

Comment: I tried to hardcode with `\ifnum \else \fi` but it only throws errors.

Comment: I think you have to use a `\noexpand` or `\unexpanded` in front of the ifnum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply is a question of the correct joining and attaching of the boxes which build the exercise's headings. Please note that the word *Exercise* is added automatically in the code below.

Remaining questions:

- Should the word *Exercise* appear above of every exercise? (This is what my solution does right now)
- Should *Exercise* and the exercise number have different formatting (like in the OP and what my solution does right now)?
- Should solutions have the same or a different layout?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{exsheets,calc}% the calc package provides \widthof

\newlength\headingsep
\setlength\headingsep{1em}
\newlength\exercisemargin
% use \textbf{Exercise} if you want bold headings, see also below
\setlength\exercisemargin{\widthof{Exercise}+\headingsep}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{custom}{default}{
  above = \baselineskip ,
  runin  = true ,
  number-pre-code = \bfseries , % only necessary if points should have a
                                % different formatting than the title
  join = { title[r,b]number[r,t](0pt,0pt) } ,
  attach = { main[r,t]title[r,t](-\headingsep,\baselineskip) }
}

\SetupExSheets{
  headings = custom ,
  headings-format = , % important if ``Exercise'' should be printed with \normalfont!
  question/pre-hook  = \begin{addmargin}[\exercisemargin]{0cm},
  question/post-hook = \end{addmargin},
  counter-within = section ,
  counter-format = ch.se.qu
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}     
\chapter{Topic 2}

\section{Section}

\begin{question}
  I'm an excercise. \lipsum[4]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  I'm a solution.
\end{solution}

\section{Section}

\begin{question}
  I'm an excercise. \lipsum[4]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  I'm a solution.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Only minor changes are necessary if *Exercise* shouldn't be part of the question heading:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{exsheets,calc}% the calc package provides \widthof

\newlength\headingsep
\setlength\headingsep{1em}
\newlength\exercisemargin

\setlength\exercisemargin{\widthof{Exercise}+\headingsep}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{custom}{default}{
  runin  = true ,
  attach = { main[r,t]number[r,t](-\headingsep,0pt) }
}

\SetupExSheets{
  headings = custom ,
  question/pre-hook  = \begin{addmargin}[\exercisemargin]{0cm},
  question/post-hook = \end{addmargin},
  counter-within = section ,
  counter-format = ch.se.qu
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Topic 1}

\section{Section}

Exercise
\begin{question}
  I'm an excercise. \lipsum[4]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  I'm a solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  I'm an excercise. \lipsum[4]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  I'm a solution.
\end{solution}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{Topic 2}

\section{Section}

Exercise
\begin{question}
  I'm an excercise. \lipsum[4]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  I'm a solution.
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  I'm an excercise. \lipsum[4]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  I'm a solution.
\end{solution}

\section{Section}

Exercise
\begin{question}
  I'm an excercise. \lipsum[4]
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  I'm a solution.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The word _Exercise_ shouldn't appear above every exercise. It's more like a headline because after _Exercise_ are normally many exercises. That's why _Exercise_ and the exercise number have different formatting. The formatting of the solution is a little bit different: The indent of main part is the same (with `\addmargin[]{}`), but this time the number (exercise number or solution number...howsoever you want to call it) is left aligned: The number has no indent.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider see my edited answer.